# android : youtubeplayerview api configuration change issue

Tags: android, youtube-api, orientation

I am using youtubeplayerview to display youtube videos. I am having issue with handling orientation change .

Initially my video open in portrait mode , as expected. Now if i click full screen button, video opens in full screen in landscape mode . ( I do not change the orientation of the phone, but the full screen is opened in landscape mode ).

Now to watch the video , i rotate my phone 90 degrees left and watch full screen video. If i just rotate back the phone , the full screen automatically change to small scree in portrait mode.

SO looks like full screen only in landscape mode and  portrait mode always have small screen.
I do not want this behavior. I want to change the video size based on user clicking full screen or not. Not based on the phone orientation

Please help how to fix it.
I saw setting some flags for the player but could not get it working .

Answer (score 0):

You can use into the manifest for the activity android:screenOrientation="nosensor".